# Google Earth 1.0 Type Library Missing

Tags: google-earth, excel, vba

I've been running Excel to Google Earth Dashboards for some time through VBA on Windows 7 and Excel 2010. However, I have just tried to copy one of my workbooks to a Windows 8.1 machine on Excel 2016 and the Google Earth 1.0 Type Library is missing from VBA reference so the Google Earth links will not load.The same version of Google Earth is being run on both machines.

I have also tried this on a Windows 10 machine and cannot get it to work either. Any ideas why the Google Earth 1.0 Type Library is not available and where I can get it? A search online returns little information.

Answer (score 1):

I have since found out the latest Google Earth 64bit version changes the install location and subsequently Excel can no longer find the library (although the library doesn't seem to exist in this version anymore either)

The 32bit version keeps the install location and allows Excel to access the library.